# C++ object destroyed more than once

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, instantiation, raii

When writing some code that loads a (part of) a datastructure into graphics memory, I was surprised by this unexpected behaviour.

I've simplified the code to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Data{
    int data;
    Data(int x){
        data = x;
        cout<<"+ Data"<<endl;
    }
    ~Data(){cout<<"- Data"<<endl;}
};

struct Handle{
    // imagine some handles to video memory here
    Handle(Data d){
        // (upload data to video memory)
        cout<<"+ Handle"<<endl;
    }
    ~Handle(){
        // (deallocate the data from video memory)
        cout<<"- Handle"<<endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    vector<Handle> container;
    cout<<"start"<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        container.emplace_back(Data(i));
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"end"<<endl;
}
```

what I expected:

```
start
+ Data
+ Handle
- Data

+ Data
+ Handle
- Data

+ Data
+ Handle
- Data

+ Data
+ Handle
- Data

end
-Handle
-Handle
-Handle
-Handle
```

what I got:

```
start
+ Data
+ Handle
- Data
- Data

+ Data
+ Handle
- Data
- Handle
- Data

+ Data
+ Handle
- Data
- Handle
- Handle
- Data

+ Data
+ Handle
- Data
- Data

end
- Handle
- Handle
- Handle
- Handle
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: You should declare a copy constructor, so you can really trace how many objects are created...

Comment: You've got an unused parameter in `Handle`s constructor. Did you count on that? Also, `container.emplace_back(i);` so you don't make an unnecessary temporary.

Comment: `emplace_back` is C++11.. There is no need for it now because there is no temporary created in C++ 11 with push_back: `void push_back(T&& value);`

Comment: @Macmade thank you! that explains the extra destructor calls.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames the Handle constructor takes a Data, so emplace_back(Data(i)) constructs a Handle with the given Data, right?

Comment: cppguy answers the additional Data copies in the answers. I'm adding this comment to mention that the additional Handles can be gotten rid of by using reserve() on the vector before hand so it doesn't need to resize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This modification of your code may help you better see what's happening.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Data{
    int data;
    static int allcount;
    int count;
    Data(int x) : count(allcount) {
        data = x;
        allcount++;
        cout<<"+ Data "<< count <<endl;
    }
    Data(const Data &d) : count(allcount) {
        allcount++;
        cout<<"+ Data(copy of " << d.count << ") "<< count <<endl;
    }
    ~Data(){cout<<"- Data "<< count <<endl;}
};

struct Handle{
    static int allcount;
    int count;
    // imagine some handles to video memory here
    Handle(Data d) : count(allcount) {
        allcount++;
        // (upload data to video memory)
        cout<<"+ Handle " << count << endl;
    }
    Handle(const Handle &h) : count(allcount) {
        allcount++;
        cout<<"+ Handle(copy of " << h.count << ") "<< count <<endl;
    }
    ~Handle(){
        // (deallocate the data from video memory)
        cout<<"- Handle " << count <<endl;
    }
};

int Handle::allcount=0;
int Data::allcount=0;

int main(){
    vector<Handle> container;
    cout<<"start"<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        container.emplace_back(Data(i));
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"end"<<endl;
}
```

What it does is to keep track of each allocation and deallocation with an integer to uniquely identify each.  Copy constructors are also explicitly added.  When I run this on my system I get the following:

```
start
+ Data 0
+ Data(copy of 0) 1
+ Handle 0
- Data 1
- Data 0

+ Data 2
+ Data(copy of 2) 3
+ Handle 1
- Data 3
+ Handle(copy of 0) 2
- Handle 0
- Data 2

+ Data 4
+ Data(copy of 4) 5
+ Handle 3
- Data 5
+ Handle(copy of 2) 4
+ Handle(copy of 1) 5
- Handle 2
- Handle 1
- Data 4

+ Data 6
+ Data(copy of 6) 7
+ Handle 6
- Data 7
- Data 6

end
- Handle 4
- Handle 5
- Handle 3
- Handle 6
```

As you can see, the `Handle` is copied multiple times.  This is because they need to be copied when the container they're in is resized.  If you add the line

```
container.reserve(4);
```

just before the line that prints "start", I think you'll see what you expected to see in the first place.  That is, no `Handle` copies.

Answer (score 4):

`Handle(Data d)` is taking a `Data` object by value so the `d` in your Handle constructor is actually a copy of the object you passed into Handle's constructor. Since a copy had to be created, a copy had to be destroyed too. Its scope is the body of Handle's constructor so that's why it happens after "+ Handle"

Here's what the constructor should look like:

```
Handle(const Data& d){
    // (upload data to video memory)
    cout<<"+ Handle"<<endl;
}
```

The const reference is to prevent an unnecessary copy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it explains the extra data copies, but it doesn't explain the extra Handle copies which is giving me trouble.